# Griffiths E&M questions about example 6.1

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, magnetic-moment

[image]

[image]

I understand why $K_b = M\mbox{sin}\theta \hat{\phi}$ but when I try to use this to calculate the magnetic field, I keep coming up with an integral that cancels itself out and I don't understand how Griffiths computes the integral. I think I may be setting it up wrong or something is missing conceptually. Here is my logic:
\begin{equation}
A(r) = \frac{\mu_0}{4\pi}\int \frac{K(r')}{|r-r'|}da'
\end{equation}

Since $K(r') = M\mbox{sin}\theta \hat{\phi}$ in order to integrate this we have to express this with respect to cartesian unit vectors. Using $\hat{\phi} = -\mbox{sin}\phi \hat{x}+ \mbox{cos}\phi \hat{y}$, we have,
\begin{equation}
K_b = -M\mbox{sin}\theta\mbox{sin}\phi\hat{x} + M\mbox{sin}\theta\mbox{cos}\phi \hat{y}
\end{equation}
Moreover, in spherical coordinates, $|r-r'| = \sqrt{R^2+r^2-2Rr\mbox{cos}\theta}$, where $R$ is the radius of the sphere. And the integration thingy is $R^2\mbox{sin}\theta d\phi d\theta$. Then the potential is,

\begin{equation}
A(r) = \frac{\mu_0}{pi}\int \frac{-M\mbox{sin}\theta\mbox{sin}\phi\hat{x}}{\sqrt{R^2+r^2-2Rr\mbox{cos}\theta}}R^2\mbox{sin}\theta d\phi d\theta + \frac{\mu_0}{\pi}
\int \frac{M\mbox{sin}\theta\mbox{cos}\phi \hat{y}}{\sqrt{R^2+r^2-2Rr\mbox{cos}\theta}}R^2\mbox{sin}\theta d\phi d\theta
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
= \frac{\mu_0}{4\pi}\int_0^{\pi}\frac{-M\mbox{sin}\theta\hat{x}}{\sqrt{R^2+r^2-2Rr\mbox{cos}\theta}}R^2\mbox{sin}\theta d\theta \int_0^{2\pi}\mbox{sin}\phi d\phi + 
\frac{\mu_0}{4\pi}\int_0^{\pi}\frac{M\mbox{sin}\theta\hat{y}}{\sqrt{R^2+r^2-2Rr\mbox{cos}\theta}}R^2\mbox{sin}\theta d\theta \int_0^{2\pi}\mbox{cos}\phi d\phi
\end{equation}

But then
\begin{equation}
\int_0^{2\pi} \mbox{sin}\phi d\phi = \int_0^{2\pi} \mbox{cos}\phi d\phi =0
\end{equation}
So this would mean $A(r) = 0$, which can't be the case since $B = \nabla \times A$.

If anyone could point to where I went wrong that would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you refered back to example 5.11? Because Griffiths performs no integral here and it would help more if the previously mentioned example was also in this question.

Comment: Your denominator is the result of evaluating $\mathbf{A} (\mathbf{r})$ on the z-axis, i.e. $\theta = 0$ (btw, you should have $\theta'$ on your expression, not $\theta$). Do not do that and you'll have a more complicated denominator. which should avoid the cancelling.

Comment: @Triatticus It was not super helpful since in ex. 5.11 the $\omega \times r$ vector had another component without sin$\phi$ or cos$\phi$. In the example the components with those terms did cancel.

Comment: @SomeUser If $\theta =0$ then both integrals would equal $0$ due to the sin$\theta$ term in both integrals.

Comment: What I'm saying is there isn't any integration to do, and that's the point Griffiths is trying to make here, Iof course you are interested in specifically how to set up the integral anyways regardless of what the example is about correct?

Comment: There is a problem with your notation. Field points should not be primed whereas the integration variables yes. You used that notation until you wrote the first integral in their cartesians components, then you decided to drop that prime. What I'm saying is that your denominator on the integrals corresponds to evaluate $\mathbf{A}$ in $\theta = 0$. You shouldn't do that if you want to compute the rotor after. Your denominator should read $\sqrt{ [r\cos(\phi)\sin(\theta) - r'\cos(\phi')\sin(\theta')]^{2} + \cdots }$

Comment: @Triatticus yes that is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have
\begin{equation*}
\mathbf{A}(\mathbf{r}) = 
\frac{\mu_{0}}{4\pi} \iint \frac{\mathbf{K}(\mathbf{r'})}{|\mathbf{r} - \mathbf{r'}|} \text{d}^{2}S'
\end{equation*}

I'll only write the $x$ component.
\begin{equation*}
A_{x}(\mathbf{r}) = \frac{\mu_{0}}{4\pi}
\iint \frac{-M\sin(\theta')\sin(\phi')}
{|\mathbf{r} - \mathbf{r'}|} {R}^{2} \sin(\theta') \text{d}\theta'\text{d}\phi'
\end{equation*}

where
\begin{align*}
|\mathbf{r} - \mathbf{r'}| &= 
\sqrt{
\left[ r\cos(\phi)\sin(\theta) - R\cos(\phi')\sin(\theta')\right]^{2} +
\left[ r\sin(\phi)\sin(\theta) - R\sin(\phi')\sin(\theta')\right]^{2} +
\left[r\cos(\theta) - R\cos(\theta')\right]^{2}} \\
&=
\sqrt{r^{2} + {R}^{2} - 2rR
\left[ \cos(\theta)\cos(\theta') + \sin(\theta)\sin(\theta') \left(\cos(\phi)\cos(\phi') + \sin(\phi)\sin(\phi')\right)
\right]}
\end{align*}

Your denominator is the result of evalutating $\theta = 0$ on this complete denominator. It is indeed true that the vector potential vanishes on the $z$ axis
\begin{equation*}
\mathbf{A}(r,\theta = 0, \phi) = \mathbf{A}(x = 0, y = 0, z) = \mathbf{0} \, ,
\end{equation*}
but you need the vector potential in all space in order to compute the rotor.

This integral may not have an analitic solution, that might be the reason why Griffiths followed another approach.

Comment: why would A vanish on the z axis? isn't this just analogous to finding the vector potential in the center of a current loop? which isn't zero

Comment: Right now, I don't have the expression for the vector potential for a current loop, but at least the dipolar term on the expansion is indeed $0$ ($\mathbb{m} \parallel \mathbf{\hat{z}}$).

Comment: there is a magnetic field at the center of a current loop though. unless A is zero but B isn't.

Comment: I'm not saying the magnetic field is zero, I'm saying the vector potential is (with this chosen gauge). For the magnetic field to be zero, $\nabla \times \mathbf{A} = \mathbf{0}$ which shouldn't be the case.